# Where is the error in the following json

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json in following format( Its pretty long:( Please feel free to edit it in order to copy it.

http://jsfiddle.net/kZpBu/

and when i paste it here http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/
  to visualize it.. it throws an error

I am trying to convert to this format
http://jsfiddle.net/uNqe6/

which is very heirachical in nature whereas my jsons are bit flat..

It says that it was expecting an EOF instead of ","
How is first format different than second?
Thanks

Ahh.. they dont let me post without a code snippet

```
{"name": "topic 0", "children": [{"name": "river", "size": 260462}, {"name": "water", "size": 154470}, {"name": "lake", "size": 137116}, {"name": "mountain", "size": 87756}..
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsonlint.com is a great site for things like this.

The error is in the fact that your JSON is in the following format:

```
{
  // stuff
} , {
  // stuff
}
```

objects separated by commas are not valid json.  I suspect you want this to be an array, in which case you need to surround it in `[]`:

```
[{
  // stuff
} , {
  // stuff
}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Your JSON is defining two objects like:

```
{"name":"topic 0" /*array*/},{"name":"topic 1" /*array*/}
```

which is a problem for the parser that is expecting an object. If you mean an array for the two, wrap the JSON in `[]` as:

```
[{"name":"topic 0" /*array*/},{"name":"topic 1" /*array*/}]
```

and http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ is happy.

Answer (score 2):

Use http://jsonlint.com. It'll show you exactly where your error is.

```
Parse error on line 205:
...48        }    ]},{    "name": "top
--------------------^
Expecting 'EOF'
```

Answer (score 1):

Between the two JSON objects that aren't in an array.

```
{
    "name": "topic 0",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "river",
            "size": 260462
        },
// Lots of stuff deleted
        {
            "name": "great",
            "size": 24348
        }
    ]

}, // Right here.

{
    "name": "topic 1",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "number",
            "size": 59354
        },
// Elided
```